# T-SQL setting int on a column based on random p-key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the following script below. I am pretty much looking to update a colomn called "C1Int" with the number 1234567 randomly based on the pkey of the row.

I created a random generator for the pkey that uses 1 as the min and the total rows as the max.

Then there is a loop that should update the rows over and over based on the number in the WHILE statement. When I run it, it just updates one random row with the 1234567 number and even though its still running the loop, it never updates anything else. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

```
DECLARE @a INT 
DECLARE @maxpkey INT
DECLARE @minpkey INT
DECLARE @randompkey INT

SET @a = 1
SET @maxpkey = (select count(*) from [LoadTestTwo].[dbo].[actbenchdb.Table1])
SET @minpkey = 1
SET @randompkey = ROUND(((@maxpkey - @minpkey -1) * RAND() + @minpkey),0)


WHILE @a < 500000000000000000000
  BEGIN
UPDATE [LoadTestTwo].[dbo].[actbenchdb.Table1]
SET    C1Int = (1234567)
WHERE  Pkey = @randompkey

SET @a = @a + 1
END
```

Comment: If you ask me this is a case of "just because you can, doesn't mean you should"... sorry for not trying to enable you by giving a more constructive advice.

Comment: What is the point of this? With such a ridiculously high number of iterations through the loop you are likely to update all the rows. You could shorten this immensely with just a simple update to update the entire table. It would be way simpler to understand and it will be a lot faster because it doesn't have to perform the calculation 500 hundred quintillion times.

Comment: Its a pseudo load generator for a fully populated database. We are going to create a DB with that column I specified it will have 1234567 on each row. I need to randomly keep setting (or resetting I guess) that integer based on a random Pkey in the database. If you can suggest something better, please do so. Its just what I threw together quickly. DBA is not my specialty.

Comment: Why does the primary key need to be random? Why can't you just give the column a default of that value so all new rows get it, or if it should really be constant for all rows, why bother having the column at all, or at least have a computed column?

Comment: The tables are all going to be pre-populated with that value already. I just want to go around and randomly reset the value based. The randomness is based on pkey value. So it will select a existing row based on a random pkey value and update the column with the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current loop only updates a single row because you set the random key outside the loop and then just run the same update statement 500,000,000,000,000,000,000 times (Which assuming 1 million executions per second would still take 15 million years to complete, and would likely hit all your records anyway).

It is clear what you are trying to do, I just don't know why you would want to randomly change data in your database. Anyway, I may not understand why, but I can at least say how, if you want to update *n* random rows, then rather than running a loop *n* times, it would be better to perform a single update:

```
DECLARE @n INT = 100; -- NUMBER OF RANDOM ROWS TO UPDATE

UPDATE t 
SET CInt = 12345467 
FROM (  SELECT TOP (@n) * 
        FROM [LoadTestTwo].[dbo].[actbenchdb.Table1] 
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    ) AS t;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are simpler and better ways to create a DB Load Generator!

[Let me Google that for you](http://bfy.tw/n2t)